# Hierarchical Timed Animation in CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, material-design

Google Design documentation guidelines show this [great transition (video)](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animation-meaningfultransitions-hierarchicaltiming4do_large_xhdpi.webm):

[image: animation in progress]

How do I recreate this in pure CSS3?

Comment: I just tried [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/xypYY/3/), hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the boxes has the same animation attached to it, they just fire at different times. You can make this happen with either transition-delay or animation-delay. The zooming up and down can be accomplished by transform: scale().

```
.box {
    background: #4285f6;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    transition: .35s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
    transform: scale(0);
}
.holder {
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
}
.holder:hover>* {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.holder>*:nth-child(2) {transition-delay: .1s}
.holder>*:nth-child(3) {transition-delay: .2s}
.holder>*:nth-child(4) {transition-delay: .3s}
.holder>*:nth-child(5) {transition-delay: .15s}
.holder>*:nth-child(6) {transition-delay: .25s}
.holder>*:nth-child(7) {transition-delay: .35s}
.holder>*:nth-child(8) {transition-delay: .4s}
```

Your html would be:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The timing might not be quite right, but here's a quick n' dirty try http://jsfiddle.net/jtup3/1/

Comment: I think that's the way to do it. Don't forget to add the vendor prefixes _-webkit-, -moz-, -o-..._ to the _transform_ and _transition_ properties for this to work in Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: I added prefixfree to the fiddle, seems to fix it.  Nice work Richard :-)